# omdbapi.com usage: actor and actress, what parameters I need?

Tags: api

I have to load data of imdb using his api www.omdbapi.com. For example if after ? you set i= id of imdb you get the details of film you are looking for.

I am not finding the way if I give word: "Brad Pitt" to get json of that api with all films of Brad Pitt.

In documentation they only show to get the information of film.

ypi can see in [www.omdbapi.com](http://www.omdbapi.com)

Could anybody help please? Anybody worked with that Api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with the API before, but to my knowledge there is no parameter for the actor. It is generally used to find specific movies and series based on name:

http://www.omdbapi.com/#parameters

Note that the API seems to no longer be free. an API key is required, which can be requested after donating money.